# Error trying to use pyad to update user account

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyad

I'm trying to update a user attribute in Active Directory using pyad. This is my code

```
from pyad import *

pyad.set_defaults(ldap_server="server.domain.local", 
username="admin", password="password")

pyad.adobject.ADObject.update_attribute(self='testuser1', attribute='mail', 
newvalue='my@email.com')
```

and this is the error i recieve.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\scripts\AD-Edit-user.py", line 12, in 
 <module>
 pyad.adobject.ADObject.update_attribute(self='testuser1', attribute='mail', 
 newvalue='my@email.com')
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
 32\lib\site-packages\pyad-0.5.20-py3.6.egg\pyad\adobject.py", line 318, in 
 update_attribute
 elif pyadutils.generate_list(newvalue) != self.get_attribute(attribute):
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

This makes me assume that I need to change the attribute type from `str` to something else. I have verified that mail is the correct attribute name.

I know ldap connection is working because i can create a user using a similar script.

Comment: can you update your question with the full Trace ?

Comment: @Edwin van Mierlo done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is how you use pyad.
Specifically in this line:

```
pyad.adobject.ADObject.update_attribute(self='testuser1', attribute='mail', 
newvalue='my@email.com')
```

if we look at the [source of pyad.adobject.ADObject](https://github.com/zakird/pyad/blob/master/pyad/adobject.py), we can see the following:

```
def update_attribute(self, attribute, newvalue, no_flush=False):
    """Updates any mutable LDAP attribute for the object. If you are adding or removing
    values from a multi-valued attribute, see append_to_attribute and remove_from_attribute."""
    if newvalue in ((),[],None,''):
        return self.clear_attribute(attribute)
    elif pyadutils.generate_list(newvalue) != self.get_attribute(attribute):
        self._set_attribute(attribute, 2, pyadutils.generate_list(newvalue))
        if not no_flush:
            self._flush()
```

`self` here is not a parameter of the function, it is a reference to the class instance. Your call includes `self='testuser1'` which is `str`.

Please lookup the documentation on how to use this function / functionality / module, [here](https://zakird.com/pyad/objects.html#adobject). You will notice that there is no "self"... other than looking into the source code I am not sure how you got to the conclusion you needed `self`.

I have no way of testing the following, but this is roughly how it should work:

```
# first you create an instance of the object, based on 
# the distinguished name of the user object which you 
# want to change
my_ad_object = pyad.adobject.ADObject.from_dn('the_distinguished_name')

# then you call the update_attribute() method on the instance
my_ad_object.update_attribute(attribute='mail', newvalue='my@email.com')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I originally left self out but got the following message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\scripts\AD-Edit-user.py", line 12, in <module>
    pyad.adobject.ADObject.update_attribute(attribute='mail', newvalue='my@email.com')
TypeError: update_attribute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: yes, that is to be expected, as you did not create an instance of the object, please see my updated answer. I could not test this. And I could not find any sample code ... but ran out of time.. good luck.

Comment: I'm still getting an error, I haven't had time to look into it but I wanted to come back and say thank you for your help and for the detail in your answer!

Comment: The last error i recieved was due to the DN being wrong I was using ou=users when i should have been using cn=users Thanks again for your help.     my_ad_object = pyad.adobject.ADObject.from_dn("cn=testuser1,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=local")

my_ad_object.update_attribute(attribute='mail', newvalue='my@email.com')